# How to write 64-bit BigInt to Buffer?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to write 64-bit BigInts into a `Buffer` in Node.js (10.7+) yet?

Or do I still have to do it in two operations?

```
let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(16);
buf.writeUInt32BE(Number(time>>32n),0,true);
buf.writeUInt32BE(Number(time&4294967295n),4,true);
```

I can't find anything promising in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), but there's other barely documented methods such as `BigInt.asUintN`, so i thought I'd ask.

Comment: Feature request is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21662

Comment: Since the latest Node.js v12.0.0, you can now use `buf.writeBigInt64BE`

Comment: Just as a note about Code and CPU optimation, which I'm not 100% sure Node doesn't do: you should never hard code in your bit masks. You should always use bit shifting so the compiler knows what you are doing. Instead use ((1 << 32n - 1). It's actually easier to read, debug, and understand, and potentially a CPU optimization, but that is secondary.

Comment: @CaleMcCollough  It'd be `((1n << 32n) - 1n)`. You can't mix BigInts and numbers. I'd be very surprised if the JIT compiler somehow runs that faster. But readability wise, yes, I can accept that. `0xFFFFFFFFn` or `0xFFFF_FFFFn` would also be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just faced with a similar problem (needing to build and write 64-bit IDs consisting of a 41-bit timestamp, 13-bit node ID, and a 10-bit counter). The largest single value I was able to write to a buffer was 48-bit using buf.writeIntLE(). So I ended up building up / writing the high 48 bits, and low 16 bits independently. If there's a better way to do it, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess they haven't implemented it yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this package?
https://github.com/substack/node-bigint#tobufferopts

Comment: I did. In fact, I'm converting some code that used to use a BigInt library into native code now, which is why I'm asking. I don't want to introduce a lib with non-native bigints to save me 2 lines of code.